# Why Axios is showing 'Invalid API Key' using the post method in React using TMDB api

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

I am trying to send a post request with Axios in react app to create a session with login but its showing "Invalid API key: You must be granted a valid key." But when I am using the TMDB explorer api with the same body query, there's no error, its returning response with a " true " status.

I have included the Authorization key in the headers but nothing is working. Please help!

**This is the api file**

```
import axios from "axios";

const BASE_URL = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3";
const TMDB_TOKEN = import.meta.env.VITE_TMDB_TOKEN;

const headers = {
  Authorization: "bearer " + TMDB_TOKEN,
};

export const fetchSessionData = async (url, body) => {
  console.log(headers);
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.post(BASE_URL + url, {
      headers,
      body: JSON.stringify(body),
    });
    return data;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

**This is how I am calling the fetchSessionData method**

```
fetchSessionData("/authentication/token/validate_with_login", data).then(
        (res) => console.log(res)
      );
```

Here the data is an object which contains the request_token,username and password

I tried to validate the request token using the Create Session(with Login) endpoint so that I can generate a session ID